# How validate a selection of at least one element (or N elements) in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

My form as field `users` (entity type). How can i add validation in order to specificity that **at least one user should be selected**? Actually i'm adding an event listener but i don't know if this is a legit solution or not:

```
public function buildForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder $builder,
    array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Titolo'
        ))
        ->add('content',  'textarea', array(
            'label' => 'Contenuto'
        ))
        ->add('sender_text',  'text', array(
            'label' => 'Mittente testuale',
        ))
        ->add('users', 'entity', array(
            'label'    => 'Destinatari',
            'class'    => 'DL\FidelityBundle\Entity\User',
            'property' => 'select_label',
            'multiple' => true
        ));
    ;

    // Valida il numero di utenti selezionati
    $builder->addEventListener(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::POST_BIND,
        function($event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if(!$data->users->isEmpty()) return;

            $msg = 'Occorre specificare almeno un utente destinatario';
            $form->get('users')->addError(new FormError($msg));
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at the validation component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

You can write a [callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) within the object you want to validate:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

public function isUsersValid(ExecutionContext $context)
{
    if ($this->users->isEmpty()) {
        $propertyPath = $context->getPropertyPath() . '.users';
        $context->setPropertyPath($propertyPath);
        $context->addViolation('Occorre specificare almeno un utente destinatario', array(), null);
    }
}
```

See the callback constraint page how to add this constraint to your entity (this depens if you are using annotations or yaml/xml).

Comment: You are retrieving the data in your event listener with `$data = $event->getData();`. I don't think this is a doctrine collection? Could you show the `getDefaultOptions` method of the type class?

Answer (score 20):

As of Symfony 2.1, you can use the `Count` constraint. If you are on 2.0, you can simply copy the constraint to your project and adapt its namespaces and its API (which was slightly changed between 2.0 and 2.1).

```
/**
 * @Assert\Count(min = 1, minMessage = "Occorre specificare almeno un utente destinatario") 
 */
private $users = new ArrayCollection();
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using Count constraint validator?
I suppose your code will look like this:

```
->add('users', 'entity', array(
        'label'    => 'Destinatari',
        'class'    => 'DL\FidelityBundle\Entity\User',
        'property' => 'select_label',
        'multiple' => true,
        'constraints' => new Count(
            array('min' => 1, 'minMessage' => "Please select at least one user')
        ),
    ));
```